# DataTable expression refering to other DataTable column

Tags: c#, datatable, expression, formula

I have 2 DataTables, `DT1` and `DT2`.

`DT1` has columns `A1`, `B1` and `DT2` has columns `A2`, `B2`.
I'd like to add an expression to `A1`like `A1 = A2 + B2`

Is this possible to do without joining or merging the 2 DataTables, this is similar to the way spreadsheets operate?.

Is there any other way to do this, any other data structures or techniques apart from DataTable that would get this done?.

I see that a DataTable won't be able the deduce from a string the tables that the columns belong to?
Is it possible that we can add these 2 `DataTables` to a `DataSet` and then do the expression referring to tables present in the `DataSet`.

**Edit:**

I have used addition as an example however the expressions can have multiple combinations of math and logic operators and sometimes basic math functions.

Comment: You can use this library https://github.com/codingseb/ExpressionEvaluator

Comment: @viveknuna Do i need to create variables for the datatable cells and then feed it into the expression evaluator? Or is there some other mechanism to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See code below

```
            DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
            dt1.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(string));
            dt1.Columns.Add("A1", typeof(int));
            dt1.Columns.Add("B1", typeof(int));

            DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
            dt2.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(string));
            dt2.Columns.Add("A2", typeof(int));
            dt2.Columns.Add("B2", typeof(int));

            DataSet ds = new DataSet()
            ds.Tables.Add(dt1);
            ds.Tables.Add(dt2);

            foreach(DataRow row in dt1.AsEnumerable())
            {
                DataRow match = dt2.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<string>("ID") == row.Field<string>("ID")).First();
                row["A1"] = match.Field<int>("A2") + match.Field<int>("B2");

            }
```

Comment: I was looking for various kinds of  expressions, between columns and its not limited to addition, it could have a combination of various math and logic operators and some basic funnctions. My question may have not been that clear, I will edit it to convey that.

Comment: I suspected that was the case since you used LIKE.  Above is just an example and you can modify as needed.  The code just shows how to enumerate through the two tables.  You need to have a common column between the two tables to be able to join which was missing from your posting.

Comment: As an example for an expression like `((A1/A2)*B1) + B2`, I was trying to use this as an expression string in the 3rd parameter of dt.Columns.Add(), however it does not permit cross table references.

Comment: You would need to use a formula and create a dataset with both tables in the set.  Then see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.compute?view=net-6.0 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression?view=net-6.0

Comment: Will a dataset auto deduce the tables that the columns belong to, eg. if we use `((A1/A2)*B1) + B2` will the DataSet know that `A1` belongs to `Dt1` and `A2` belongs to `Dt2`

Comment: If I used that formula in a column in `Dt2` I get an exception `Cannot find column [A1]`

Comment: use something like ds.Tables[dt1]

Comment: I tried putting an expression on one of the tables like this`dt2.Columns.Add("c2", typeof(int), "(ds.Tables[dt1].Columns[a1] + ds.Tables[dt1].Columns[b1]) - (a2 + b2)");` But it gives `'Syntax error: Missing operand after '[dt1]' operator.'`

Comment: See salesSet.Relations.Add in following second  example : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable?view=net-7.0#examples

Comment: I think we are doing something wrong, even after adding the relation i'm getting the same error. I added relation like this `DataRelation rel = new DataRelation("one2one", ds.Tables["dt1"].Columns["id"], ds.Tables["dt2"].Columns["id"]);
            ds.Relations.Add(rel);`

Comment: Did you add the tables to the ds?  I modified the code above to add table to the dataset.